# EB throwing nodejs version error during deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs app on elastic beanstalk. I create the environment with nodejs 10, matching the nodejs version in my `package.json`. The deployment fails, and the logs show

> An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Install customer specified node.js version]. Stop running the command. Error: unsupported node version **v10.23.1**, please specify any of node versions in [v10.0.0 v10.1.0 v10.10.0 v10.11.0 v10.12.0 v10.13.0 v10.14.0 v10.14.1 v10.14.2 v10.15.0 v10.15.1 v10.15.2 v10.15.3 v10.16.0 v10.16.1 v10.16.2 v10.16.3 v10.17.0 v10.18.0 v10.18.1 v10.19.0 v10.2.0 v10.2.1 v10.20.0 v10.20.1 v10.21.0 v10.22.0 v10.22.1 v10.23.0 **v10.23.1** v10.23.2 v10.23.3 v10.24.0 v10.3.0 v10.4.0 v10.4.1 v10.5.0 v10.6.0 v10.7.0 v10.8.0 v10.9.0]

My `package.json` include:

```
"engines": {
      "node": "v10.23.1", # I've tried 10.23.1, ^10.23.1, etc
      "npm": ">=6.14.10"
    }
```

This error appears to be non-sensical - am I missing something about EB?

Comment: remove the " v" from the engines declaration i.e.  "engines": { "node" : "10.23.1" }

Comment: That was how I had it originally, then the error would be the same except `unsupported node version 10.23.1`, hence why I tried adding `v`